# Value of type 'DetailViewController' has no member 'word'

Tags: swift

I am new to Xcode programming and I came across this error while working on a Dictionary UISplitViewController project.
I made a "Word" class and a function, however when I try to assemble them in the AppDelegate.swift , I get the following error: "Value of type 'DetailViewController' has no member 'word' ".

Every Outlet is already properly linked to each of their label in the Detail View Controller at the Main.Storyboard .

```
//"Word" class

class Word {
let name: String
let meaning: String
let numberOfTimesTapped: String

init(name: String, meaning: String, numberOfTimesTapped: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.meaning = meaning
    self.numberOfTimesTapped = numberOfTimesTapped
    }
}

//"words" function in the DetailViewController.swift

import UIKit

let words = [
Word(name: "Home", meaning: "A place where one lives", numberOfTimesTapped: "5"),
Word(name: "Place", meaning: "A particular position, point, or area in space; a location.", numberOfTimesTapped: "3"),
Word(name: "Like", meaning: "Having the same characteristics or qualities as; similar to.", numberOfTimesTapped: "1")
]


class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

class Word {
    let name: String
    let meaning: String
    let numberOfTimesTapped: String

    init(name: String, meaning: String, numberOfTimesTapped: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.meaning = meaning
        self.numberOfTimesTapped = numberOfTimesTapped
    }

}

@IBOutlet weak var WordLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var DescriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var NumberOfTimesTappedLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var word: Word? {
        didSet {
            refreshUI()

        }
    }

    func refreshUI() {
        loadViewIfNeeded()
        WordLabel.text = word?.name
        DescriptionLabel.text = word?.meaning
        NumberOfTimesTappedLabel.text = word?.numberOfTimesTapped
    }

//Content inside of MasterViewController.swift
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            guard let splitViewController = window?.rootViewController as? UISplitViewController,
                let leftNavController =  splitViewController.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController,
                let masterViewController = leftNavController.topViewController as? MasterViewController,
                let detailViewController = splitViewController.viewControllers.last as? DetailViewController
                else { fatalError() }

            let firstWord = masterViewController.words.first
            detailViewController.word = firstWord //THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR "Value of type 'DetailViewController' has no member 'word'"

            return true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable is not visible because it is inside method `viewDidLoad` and this makes it visible just inside `viewDidLoad`'s scope.

I guess you need to have it on class scope as controller's property, so just move it to **class scope** from method together with method `refreshUI()`

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var word: Word? {
        didSet { refreshUI() }
    }

    func refreshUI() {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: I did this, but now I am getting a "Use of unresolved identifier 'refreshUI'" next to didSet { refreshUI() }

Comment: @VeloPietoso the same problem. Check edited answer.